# React-native APk gerada nao funciona

Tags: react-native

Bom dia galera, é o seguinte comecei agora no react-native  e fiz uma pequena aplicação segui como na documentação para gerar uma apk https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html  mas quando tento abrir ela no celular ou emulador ela não funciona,  nem chega a abrir... tou quebrando a cabeça nisso desde ontem

Comment: As aplicações React-Native hoje são geradas de muitas maneiras pra te responder assim de bate pronto. Antes de te dizer a forma que você vai gerar a apk, preciso saber a forma com que você construiu a sua aplicação em primeiro lugar. Você seguiu o tutorial básico de criar uma aplicação com código nativo, ou você criou uma aplicação com expo?

Comment: O Tutorial que você seguiu é para o primeiro tipo. Para o segundo, você vai utilizar o próprio expo para compilar e gerar sua aplicação. Para isso, siga os passos desse tutorial:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html

Comment: Se vc abrir o emulador e com o terminal na pasta do projeto der o comando `react-native run-android` o aplicativo funciona no emulador?

Comment: funciona sim, por isso não entendo o porque de quando tento gerar a apk ele não abrir no celular.

Answer (score 1):

Uma vez passei por esse problema. Eu apaguei os arquivos da pasta C:\SeuApp\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release - (O arquivo output.json e o .apk que estavam dentro dessa pasta). Depois executei o comando gradlew assembleRelease novamente.

Quando instalei o aplicativo o mesmo funcinou.